# How to attach file stored in Document directory in ionic capacitor in email composer

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I have application which is developed using Ionic 4 and capacitor 1.1.1 . In this i am creating file and sending as email attachment.File i am able to create in document directory but unable to attach in email composer. File path of file i am getting is like this "file:///storage/emulated/0/Documents/file1.pdf'. 
When email composer(Cordova plugin) open ,it can not attach it as attachment.

So how i can attach generated file as attachment from Document directory in email composer.